# I get this error when using react.js yup: TypeError: field.resolve is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I use Yup validation for form. I have dynamic object value from API. So i tried the following yup schematic.
But this error is returning:

image for error

[image: 1]

Can anyone help if you know the solution?

My code is :

```
const ActivitySchema = yup.object().shape({
    Activity: yup.lazy((value) => {
        if (value) {
            const ValidationObject = {
                ActivityName: yup.string().required(''),
                Answers: yup.lazy((val) => {
                    if (val) {
                        const ValidObject = {
                            LanguageName: yup.string().required(''),
                            Answer: yup.string().required('').max(maxChar, ''),
                        }

                        const NewEnt = Object.keys(val)?.reduce((acc, key) => ({
                            ...acc,
                            [key]: yup.object().shape(ValidObject)
                        }))

                        return yup.object().shape(NewEnt)
                    }
                    return yup.mixed('').notRequired('')
                })
            }

            const NewEntries = Object.keys(value)?.reduce((acc, key) => ({
                ...acc,
                [key]: yup.object().shape(ValidationObject)
            }))
            return yup.object().shape(NewEntries)
        }
        return yup.mixed('').notRequired('')
    }),
    ActivityFiles: yup.array().min(1, ''),
})

const Activities= {
    "Activity": {
      "042ab05d-eff7-420d-84bd-be7535da0f7e": {
        "ActivityName": "ActivityName",
        "Answers": {
          "en": {
            "LanguageName": "English",
            "Answer": ""
          },
          "fr": {
            "LanguageName": "French",
            "Answer": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "29102f46-f2b3-4050-87a4-92eaf31ddadb": {
        "ActivityName": "ActivityName...",
        "Answers": {
          "en": {
            "LanguageName": "English",
            "Answer": ""
          },
          "fr": {
            "LanguageName": "French",
            "Answer": ""
          }
        }
      },
    "ActivityFiles": null
  }

ActivitySchema.isValid(Activities).then((valid) => {
    if (valid) { 
      console.log("validation ok.")
    } else {
      console.log("validation is not ok.")
    }
})
```

I searched but all I could find this solution. :
.required (don't use),
.required() (use like this)

But already i commit this way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

```
const ActivitySchema = yup.object().shape({
    Activity: yup.lazy((value) => {
        if (value) {
            const ValidationObject = {
                ActivityName: yup.string().required(''),
                Answers: yup.lazy((val) => {
                    if (val) {
                        const ValidObject = {
                            LanguageName: yup.string().required(''),
                            Answer: yup.string().required('').max(maxChar, ''),
                        }

                        const NewEnt = Object.entries(val)?.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
                            ...acc,
                            [key]: yup.object().shape(ValidObject)
                        }), {})

                        return yup.object().shape(NewEnt)
                    }
                    return yup.mixed('').notRequired('')
                })
            }

            const NewEntries = Object.entries(value)?.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
                ...acc,
                [key]: yup.object().shape(ValidationObject)
            }), {})

            return yup.object().shape(NewEntries)
        }
        return yup.mixed('').notRequired('')
    }
    ),
    ActivityFiles: yup.array().min(1, ''),
})
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.